# How to extract /data/ on Android without root

Tags: android, adb

My aim is to extract system folder /data from my Android phone. I was trying several answers and my plan is

1 Create backup `adb backup "-apk app.source.getcontact  -f res.adb"`  (DONE - file res.adb is created on my PC)

2 Extract data from the backup (according to this answer https://gist.github.com/AnatomicJC/e773dd55ae60ab0b2d6dd2351eb977c1 )

```
dd if=res.adb bs=24 skip=1 | zlib-flate -uncompress | tar xf -

dd: res.adb: cannot skip to specified offset
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 6,1437e-05 s, 0,0 kB/s
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried to to ad `dconv=notrunc` option to dd? `dd if=res.adb bs=24 skip=1 dconv=notrunc ...`, also try tar xvzf -

Answer (score 2):

a different route without code could be using CX File Explorer app, which will get you access to the folder, in conjunction with something like Airdroid to transfer the files

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cxinventor.file.explorer

https://www.airdroid.com/personal-b/

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I was trying both applications, but I can only find /Android/data folder (the folder is empty). I am looking for /data folder

Comment: sorry, my answer wasn't the best, seems like you need root access for the /data folder, but some apps allow for /data access for superuser or user with root